# Multiple OnFormSubmit trigger to specific spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

So, we have this task where we have a Google Form where a user submits data as a sign up for a mentoring service that gets passed on to a Spreadsheet and the user gets an e-mail as a sort of like confirmation that the sign-up did indeed happen. During this, the mentor that the user specified also gets an e-mail with some of the information that the user has sent, and a link that redirects them to a pre-filled Google Form that contains some of the information that the user submitted, and a drop-down question that basically serves as an attendance check.

Now, all of that mentioned already works. The problem is, the way it is set-up is that there are 2 Google Forms that direct to the same spreadsheet, just in different tabs. If I try to use OnFormSubmit as a trigger for the functions that allows for the emails to be sent, what happens is both OnFormSubmit triggers occur at the same time. I've seen multiple solutions to this problem here but none of them seem to work for me. Is there a way to manually script the OnFormSubmit function to let it work only when a specific form is passed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, you should [check the guide on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future reference; especially be sure to include the code you are trying to use. Each use of [`onFormSubmit()` should only be linked to a single form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder); check your trigger settings from the dashboard. Alternatively, depending on how you have structured your code, you may need to add a conditional statement to determine which email you need to send.

Comment: If it would be helpful to know which trigger came from which form you can do that by using the event objects range to determine which response sheet was written to.

Comment: You can put an `if` condition to check the form received with the [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getid) method, and depending of one Id or the other do different things.